# Styling - Import order for Python functions and methods

Tags: python, import, pep8

I'm very, very new, so apologies in advance for what is probably a silly question.

I was wondering if there is a definitive set of rules on how to order the different import statements. I have not been able to find anything beyond the recommendation to order the imports by putting standard library imports first, then related third party ones and finally the local ones. Are there any additional rules on this? For an example, is the following order correct?

import os
import time
import datetime.datetime
from math import pi

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly.graphy_objs import Bar, Layout

from local_module_1
from local_module_1 import func_1
import local_module_1.fund_2

Just wondering if there are any unspecified rules on such imports...

I know it doesn't serve any purpose when it comes to functionality, but thought of asking in case there are any conventions.

Comment: This is a very opionated off topic question, but it depends on the styleguide that you are following. 
One of the most popular styles/tools to sort the imports in python is isort (https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/quick_start/0.-try.html)

Comment: That's a cool link! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some general conventions for ordering import statements in Python. While these conventions are not specified by the PEP8 style guide, they are widely followed and can help make your code more readable and consistent.

Here's a general guideline for how to order your import statements:

1. Standard library imports - These are Python's built-in modules, such as os, time, and datetime.
2. Related third-party imports - These are modules that are not part of the standard library but are required for your code to function, such as numpy, pandas, or matplotlib. These should be grouped together and listed alphabetically.
3. Local imports - These are modules that you have written yourself and are located within your project directory. These should also be grouped together and listed alphabetically.

Within each group of imports, you can further organize them by subgroups or individual items. For example, you can group related imports together or separate them by a blank line for clarity.

In your specific example, here's how you could reorder the imports according to this guideline:

```
import datetime
import os
import time
from math import pi

from plotly.graph_objs import Bar, Layout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import local_module_1
from local_module_1 import func_1
from local_module_1 import func_2
```

Here is a [link](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) that talks about some of these guidelines

Comment: Thank you. It's this 'within group' ordering which confused me. Especially if 'from ... ' should come before or after just 'import ...' Base on your answer, I think then it's safe to assume I can switch those two. Thanks again!